# NSFilemanager one directory back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

i want to know if there is a way to get the previous directory when working with NSFileManager...
This can be probably done by appending '..' to the current directory
([[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath] ) , but it's not a good idea at all :(

Is there another effective way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is just obtain the string representing the path of the parent directory then you could do this:

```
NSString* parentPath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

If you actually want to change to the parent directory, then just:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@".."];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use the [`stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingLastPathComponent) method in `NSString`. As per your question, you'd do something like:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* currentDirectoryPath = [fileManager currentDirectoryPath];
NSString* previousDirectory = [currentDirectoryPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```